# Merge multiple no header csv files with same row length and different column number python

Tags: python, pandas, csv, merge

As the post's title, what I found on internet are mainly merging with header. Browsing around only gives me this only code that can return a result

```
import pandas as pd
import glob
interesting_files = glob.glob("*.csv")
df_list = []
for filename in sorted(interesting_files):
    df_list.append(pd.read_csv(filename))
full_df = pd.concat(df_list)

full_df.to_csv('output.csv')
```

`
but the result is not good at all as in this picture:
[image]

what I want is just like this
[image]

***EDIT***
I found this one actually works really good for my case.

```
import pandas as pd
import glob
import csv

interesting_files = glob.glob("*.csv")
df_list = []
for filename in sorted(interesting_files):
    df_list.append(pd.read_csv(filename, header=None))
full_df = pd.concat(df_list, ignore_index=True, axis=1)
        
full_df.to_csv('Route_data.csv') #,header = ['a','b',...], index=False) for csv output header index=False)
```

additional code to delete the old files that just merged makes this even more powerful

Answer (score 0):

You can use:

```
pd.concat([df1, df2], axis=1)
```

### Example:

```
import pandas as pd
df1 = pd.DataFrame([*zip([1,2,3],[4,5,6])])
print(df1)
df2 = pd.DataFrame([*zip([7,8,9],[10,11,12])])
print(df2)
df_combined = pd.concat([df1, df2], axis=1)
print(df_combined)
```

#### Output:

```
df1>
   0  1
0  1  4
1  2  5
2  3  6

df2>
   0   1
0  7  10
1  8  11
2  9  12

df_combined>
   0  1  0   1
0  1  4  7  10
1  2  5  8  11
2  3  6  9  12
```

### DataFrame Example:

```
import pandas as pd
df1 = pd.read_csv("/path/file1.csv", header=None)
print(df1)
df2 = pd.read_csv("/path/file2.csv", header=None)
print(df2)
df_combined = pd.concat([df1, df2], axis=1)
print(df_combined)
```

Comment: Hi but how can I use this for my csv files?

Comment: I've edited my answer.

Comment: In case I just want to make path to my csv default so that I can repeat the process many times, what should the ("path/file1.csv") looks like? because every time I got new data, file names will not be the same as before. Thx!